# ExtJS7: Disable resource compression for CMD packages in package.json

Tags: extjs6, sencha-cmd, extjs7

We have a custom ExtJS CMD package created and used for main application. CMD package uses external js that is already minified/compressed. However on production build for app ExtJS again compresses already compressed file, leading to errors in app wherever those external resources are referenced.

Do we have any flag that turns of compression in package.json for externally included resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one answer would be to simply not package the external JS with your app, but to serve it separately. Guessing that's not what you want to do, though...

So, to package the file and *not* have it be compressed, you edit the `app.json`. In particular, the `production` block, where there should be a `js` entry. Make it look something like this:

```
  "production": {
    "js": [
      {"path": "app.js", "bundle": true},
      {"path": "external_file_that_should_not_be_compressed.js", "compress": false }
    ],
    ...
   },
```